# Angular 2 component as "layout" with other component passed inside

Tags: angular

I have fully funcional app with routings etc. Now I need to add custom forms into existing component.

- To dashboard component which is child of app component we are passing `<tile></tile>` component which is a simple layout, smth like box with some content inside(title, hour, description).
- Now I need to pass custom html with forms, inputs etc to the `<tile></tile>`

Is it possible?

Comment: Do you want to have the `title` component inside the `dashboard` component? `<dashboard> <title></title> </dashboard>`?

Comment: Some code will help.

Comment: update the post with more code, if possible a working plunker

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure about passing custom HTML with forms, but for inputs/variables you can do the following.

Assuming your component is called TileComponent:

In your tile.component.ts file you would need to declare input variables. Edit your import to include Input (i.e. `import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';`). Then inside your class include the relevant variables that will be passed through, in this case: `@Input() title: string;`, `@Input() hour: string;`, `@Input() description: string;`.

Then in your tile.component.html file you would get the variables like so:
 `<p>{{title}} - {{description}} - Runtime: {{hour}}<p>`, for example.

Where you are calling the component, for example on dashboard.component.html, you would simply need to assign variables from inside dashboard.component.ts to the variables you want to pass through, e.g.: `<title [title]="dashTitleVariable" [description]="dashDescVariable" [hour]="dashHourVariable]></title>`